# How to fix RichAPI error in word javascript API (Trying to add an image into the document)

Tags: javascript, xml, ms-word

So im making a add in for word and ive been getting this issue:

--

Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: GeneralException
at new n (word-win32-16.01.js:25:246592)
at i.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (word-win32-16.01.js:25:310758)
at word-win32-16.01.js:25:308821

--
This is the code thats throwing the error:

```
    function insertImage(baseUrl) {
      Word.run(function (context) {

        // Get the current selection
        var selection = context.document.getSelection();

        // Insert the image into the document
        var picture = selection.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(baseUrl, Word.InsertLocation.before);

        // Queue a command to load the picture
        context.load(picture);
      
        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands
        return context.sync().then(function () {
          console.log("Image inserted successfully");
        });
      });
```

baseUrl is an base64 url that has been converted in an previous function

this function:

```
    function toBase64URL(url, callback) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function() {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function() {
              callback(reader.result);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.send();
    }
```

Im kinda new to this stuff still a student

Ive tried changing my input different images it changed nothing

Ive also given it all headers methods ext.

So far nothing has worked and i cant find any solutions that work online.

---

EDIT

Ive done some research and tested some things as one of you reccomended but im still not making it work.

I have tho taken a picture of the error maybe this gives some more information, it also includes some extra information and the base64 string

[Error from taskpane.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nga50.jpg)

The answer for anyone looking in the future is related to the comment under my post

"Perhaps this: The documentation for readAsDataUrl at developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/… says "Note: The blob's result cannot be directly decoded as Base64 without first removing the Data-URL declaration preceding the Base64-encoded data. To retrieve only the Base64 encoded string, first remove data:*/*;base64, from the result.""

I researched into this and stripping the base64 string from data:*/*;base64, worked

here is the function for anyone who needs it
var base64Stripped = baseUrl.split(',')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nga50.jpg);

Comment: Perhaps this: The documentation for readAsDataUrl at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL says "Note: The blob's result cannot be directly decoded as Base64 without first removing the Data-URL declaration preceding the Base64-encoded data. To retrieve only the Base64 encoded string, first remove data:*/*;base64, from the result."

Comment: This worked and fixed the issue thanks